# How to extract 16-bit PNG frame from lossless x264 video

Tags: image-processing, video, ffmpeg, x264, lossless

I encoded a series of 16-bit grayscale PNGs to a lossless video with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i image%04d.png -crf 0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow output.mp4
```

I am now trying to verify that the conversion to video was truly lossless by pulling out the PNGs at the same quality.  The command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 image%04d.png
```

However, this is outputting 8-bit PNGs.  I've tried various options I've read about such as `-vcodec png` and `-qscale 0` but so far nothing appears to make it output 16-bit PNGs.

How do I extract all frames from the video at the same quality as they were going in?  Or did I make a mistake in creating the lossless video in the first place?

Edit: I get this error message when trying to use `-pix_fmt gray16be`.

> [swscaler @ 0x7fef1a8f0800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure
>   you did set range correctly

Full output:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -pix_fmt gray16be  image%04d.png
ffmpeg version 3.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1337 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj444p(pc), 512x512, 1336 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x7fef1a8f0800] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'image%04d.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, gray16be, 512x512, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 png
frame=  244 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:09.76 bitrate=N/A speed=  21x    
video:4038kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I'm happy to use a non-ffmpeg solution if there is one.

Answer (score 4):

Your lossless video is 8-bit, as that's what x264 has encoded to. And in any case, x264 does not go above 10-bit (for which you would need a standalone encoder, or a different ffmpeg binary).

`-c:v ffv1` is lossless and can encode to 16-bit gray (`gray16le`) or 16-bit RGB (e.g. `rgb48le`)

---

That swscaler line is a warning, not an error. FFmpeg does report the output as 16-bit per channel,

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, gray16be, 512x512 ...
```

but you've already lost fidelity with the downgrade of the bit depth when you encoded to H.264.

I'm unclear on what the pixel format of the input PNGs is - RGB with no hint of hue, or a monochannel encoding? I suspect the former, in which case, use

```
ffmpeg -i image%04d.png -c:v ffv1 output.nut
```

Then you can do a compare with

```
ffmpeg -i output.nut -i image%04d.png -filter_complex ssim -f null -
```

A readout of

```
SSIM R:1.000000 (inf) G:1.000000 (inf) B:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)
```

indicates full fidelity.